# Executei comando merge em branch errada como desfazer

Tags: git, versionamento

No meu projeto contem 2 branch a work e a master, hoje depois de muito tempo fui subir a versão do projeto, porém na hora de executar o `merge` acabei fazendo na branch errada, só percebi depois que havia realizado o `push` quando abri o projeto estava com os arquivos antigos, existe como desfazer este meu erro?

Segue abaixo sequencia de comando que utilizei:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Por favor me ajudem, estou bem desesperado com este meu erro :/

Comment: calma, baixa uma versao anterior ao seu merge e commita ela de novo.

Comment: @RBoschini você poderia me ajudar com a sequencia de comandos, pois eu não estou muito familiarizado com a utilização do git. (lembrando que a versão que esta no meu servidor esta bem defasada)

Comment: Já testaste `git merge --abort`?

Answer (score 7):

Você pode voltar isso usando o comando:

```
git reset --hard commit_sha
```

Existe outra forma

```
git reset --hard HEAD~6
```

Você voltará 6 commits.

Veja se isso resolve para você.

Comment: Então parceiro eu utilizei o `git reset --hard HEAD~1` porem ele voltou para uma versão mais antiga ainda, fazia um certo tempo que eu não subia as atualizações do sistema.

Comment: Você tem alguma outra sugestão? @RBoschini

Comment: pega o hash do commit que esta correto e faz assim
git reset --hard "HASH_COMMIT_SEU"

Comment: eu tentei utilizar neste meu ultimo commit que esta no print porem deu este erro                                                                                                 PS F:\Documentos\Projetos\Administracao\Administracao> git reset --hard "Cadastro de Alunos"
fatal: ambiguous argument 'Cadastro de Alunos': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
Use '--' to separate paths from revisions, like this:
'git <command> [<revision>...] -- [<file>...]'

Comment: é a hash e nao o nome "Cadastro de Alunos" que vc tem que pegar.

Comment: Desculpe a minha ignorância porem sou bem leigo quando se trata de controle de versão, como eu faço para ver o hash de um commit?

Comment: git log, o hash é algo assim commit ca82a6dff817ec66f44342007202690a93763949.

Comment: git rev-list origin

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/32615/discussion-between-vinicius-vaz-and-rboschini).

Comment: Podemos continuar esta conversa no chat?

Answer (score 3):

Antes de mais nada, verifique o ultimo commit que você fez com a versão segura da sua branch. Certifique-se que está na branch certa e use o comando:

```
git log
```

Pegue o hash da ultima versão segura. Exemplo:

```
commit 85f8oouy7c05faxiskbfcd17fcc7cfppoocca02e
Author: Guilherme Iazzetta <exemplo@email.com>
Date:   Wed Feb 5 14:05:12 2020 -0300
```

Agora faça o reset:

```
git reset --hard 85f8oouy7c05faxiskbfcd17fcc7cfppoocca02e
```

> Lembrando que o hash usado no comando acima é um exemplo, você precisa
>   substituir pelo seu.

Para mais informações, veja a [documentação](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reset).

---

Existe também o comando `git reset --hard HEAD~1`, sendo o número **1** o indice na lista de commits. Você pode ver a lista de commits usando o `git log`.